# Mousedown event not performing drawImage

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I've been working on the basic gameplay. I'm to a point where I think it should draw a card in the quadrant clicked/tapped, but nothing is happening.  I can't see what's wrong. Please help. My only clue is that this line in `mouse_down_handler`: `alert('X: ' + mouse_x + ', Y: ' + mouse_y);` isn't firing.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas#game-canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        background: lightblue;
      }
      body {
        background: darkblue;
      }    
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1_10_2_min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var card_width = 42;
      var card_height = 63;
      var x1 = 0;
      var y1 = 0;
      var width_increment = 167; // Math.floor(canvas.width / 3);
      var height_increment = 167; //Math.floor(canvas.height / 3);
      var x2 = x1 + width_increment;
      var x3 = x2 + width_increment;
      var y2 = y1 + height_increment;
      var y3 = y2 + height_increment;

    window.onload = function() {

      document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse_down_handler, false);


      var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


      var cards = cardsheet('small_playing_cards.png', card_width, card_height);


      function mouse_down_handler(e) {
        var mouse_x = e.clientX;
        var mouse_y = e.clientY;
        alert('X: ' + mouse_x + ', Y: ' + mouse_y);
        play_move(mouse_x, mouse_y);
      };

      function play_move(x, y) {
        // tap left col
        if (x < x2) {
          // tap left box on top
          if (y < y2) {
            play_grid(x1, y1, random_number());
          // tap left middle box
          } else if (y < y3) {
            play_grid(x1, y2, random_number());
          // tap lower left box
          } else {
            play_grid(x1, y3, random_number());
          }

          // tap in center col
        } else if (x < x3) {
          // tap top center box
          if (y < y2) {
            play_grid(x2, y1, random_number());

          // tap mid center box
          } else if (y < y3) {
            play_grid(x2, y2, random_number());

          // tap lower middle box
          } else {
            play_grid(x2, y3, random_number());

          }

          // tap right col
        } else {
          // tap top right box
          if (y < y2) {
            play_grid(x3, y1, random_number());

          // tap right middle box
          } else if (y < y3) {
            play_grid(x3, y2, random_number());

          // tap lower right box  
          } else {
            play_grid(x3, y3, random_number());        
          }
        }
      };

      function play_grid(x_pos, y_pos, n) {
        if (n >= 0) {
          context.drawImage(cards[n], x_pos, y_pos);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };

      function random_number() {
        if (cards_left > 0) {
          var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards_left);
          cards = cards.splice(number, 1);
          cards_left--;
          return number;
        else {
          return false;
        }
      };

      function cardsheet(path, frameWidth, frameHeight) {

         this.image = new Image();
         this.frameHeight = frameHeight;
         this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
         this.image.src = path;

         var card_sprites_canvas = [];
         var card_sprites_context = [];
         var card_names = [
         '1d', '2d', '3d', '4d', '5d', '6d', '7d', '8d', '9d', 'Xd', 'Jd', 'Qd', 'Kd',  
         '1h', '2h', '3h', '4h', '5h', '6h', '7h', '8h', '9h', 'Xh', 'Jh', 'Qh', 'Kh',
         '1s', '2s', '3s', '4s', '5s', '6s', '7s', '8s', '9s', 'Xs', 'Js', 'Qs', 'Ks',
         '1c', '2c', '3c', '4c', '5c', '6c', '7c', '8c', '9c', 'Xc', 'Jc', 'Qc', 'Kc'];  

            framesPerRow = 13; // Math.floor(this.image.width / frameWidth);
            framesPerCol = 4;  // Math.floor(this.image.height / frameHeight);
            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < framesPerRow; i++) {
              for (j = 0; j < framesPerCol; j++) {
                card_sprites_canvas[k] = document.createElement('canvas');
                card_sprites_canvas[k].width = frameWidth;
                card_sprites_canvas[k].height = frameHeight;
                card_sprites_canvas[k].face_value = card_face_value(card_names[k]);
                card_sprites_canvas[k].suit = card_suit(card_names[k])
                card_sprites_context[k] = card_sprites_canvas[k].getContext('2d');
                card_sprites_context[k].drawImage(this.image, frameWidth * i + (i * 10), frameHeight * j + (j * 9), frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
                k++;
              }
            }

        return card_sprites_canvas;
      }
      function card_face_value(card_name) {
        suit = card_name.slice(-1);
        face_value  = card_name.split(suit)[0];
        return face_value;
      }
      function card_suit(card_name) {
        suit = card_name.slice(-1);
        return suit;
      }
    };

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <img src="small_playing_cards.png" style="display: none;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a curly brace on line 107...

```
  function random_number() {
    if (cards_left > 0) {
      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards_left);
      cards = cards.splice(number, 1);
      cards_left--;
      return number;
    // was "else {" instead of "} else {"
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```